# Rotate each element around own axis in a loop (Processing)

Tags: loops, rotation, processing, translate

I have a pattern of tiles in that I want to rotate each element around its own axis.
Right now my whole pattern waves in rotation – around the axis of the first tile top left…
How do I set it that the rotation affects every single tile in the loop?
I tried it with translate() and so on… but the logic confused me totally – i mean i did not get it…

Thank you for any kind of help or idea!

```
int horizontal;
int vertical;

void setup() {
  size(730, 1080);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);


  for (vertical = 0; vertical < 5; vertical++) {

    for (horizontal = 0; horizontal <4; horizontal++) {
      float wave = sin(radians(frameCount));
      pushMatrix();
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rotate(radians(wave*10));
      rect(182*horizontal, 216*vertical, 182, 216);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rotate`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) defines a rotation matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the rotation matrix. `rotate` therefore causes a rotation by (0, 0).
You have to center the rectangle around (0, 0), rotate it and move the rotated rectangle to the desired position with [`translate`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html):

```java
translate(182*horizontal + 91, 216*vertical + 108);
rotate(radians(wave*10));
rectMode(CENTER);
rect(0, 0, 182, 216);
```

---

Complete code:

```java
void setup() {
    size(730, 1080);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    fill(255);

    for (int vertical = 0; vertical < 5; vertical++) {

        for (int horizontal = 0; horizontal <4; horizontal++) {
            float wave = sin(radians(frameCount));
            pushMatrix();
            translate(182*horizontal + 91, 216*vertical + 108);
            rotate(radians(wave*10));
            rectMode(CENTER);
            rect(0, 0, 182, 216);
            popMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AAAH! That is the trick! Thank you so much for explaining and teaching me the logic! very helpful – thank you so much!

Comment: @Cyrill Thank you. You're welccome.